# Angular2 select issue

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

The following code used to work in Angular 2 beta *13*:

```ts
<select (change)="handleChange($event)">
    <option value="">-- please choose an option --</option>
    <option *ngFor="#option of options" [value]="option.id">{{ option.name }}</option>
</select>
```

The `options` array can be as simple as `[{id: 0, name="First"}, {id: 1, name="Second"}]`. What I mean by it used to work is that when a new selection was made I was able to get the value of the selected option. Right now the value is the same as the label (innerText of the *option*).

Now, in beta *14* and *15* the same code does not work anymore. Is it a bug with Angular 2 or was there a breaking change introduced that I need to introduce in my own code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- get the value assigned to an option by looking it up in your `options` by id
- or use `[ngValue]` (introduced in beta.15) to use object values directly

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <div>selected: {{selected1 | json}}</div>
    <select (change)="handleChange($event)">
      <option value="">-- please choose an option --</option>
      <option *ngFor="#option of options" [value]="option.id">{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>    

    <div>selected: {{selected2 | json}}</div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selected2">
      <option value="">-- please choose an option --</option>
      <option *ngFor="#option of options" [ngValue]="option">{{ option.name }}</option>
    </select>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  options = [{id: 0, name:"First"}, {id: 1, name:"Second"}];
  selected1;
  selected2 = "";

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.selected1 = this.options.filter((option) => {
      return option.id == event.target.value;
    })[0];    

  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/ab2RRn?p=preview) beta.16

Answer (score 1):

Yes, even I faced it earlier. I changed `[value]` to `[attr.value]` and it started working. 
I hope it works for you too..

Check out other changes in beta 14 and 15 [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: `attr.value` means attribute binding, i dont think this one is relate into select/option in any sense

Comment: Even if we are binding attribute here, it wouldn't affect my functionality. Right?

Comment: than why to add this attribute binding ? if it would't effect at all

Comment: Okay, so can I use [ngModel] in select instead of binding value attribute in option?

Comment: i don't know about this

Comment: I tried that as well, It works fine and functionality wise too it is all right

Answer (score 1):

I guess you only want the `id` in your `handleChange()` method?

How do you access the `id` in your method?

Try this one:

```
handleChange(evt) {
    let id = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
}
```

The shape of the `$event` object is determined by whatever raises the event. The event comes from the DOM, so `$event` must be a standard DOM event object. The `$event.target` gives us an `HTMLInputElement`, which has a value property that contains the id.

[See also Angular Docu](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html)

Comment: I think I must have been doing something wrong, it now appears to be working fine. I was indee using `(<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value` to get the value.